# Missing owner.entityId field when listing objects

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage

According to this document https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource listing objects in a bucket with `projection=full` parameter should return information about the owner of the object in form of 2 fields: `entity` and `entityId`. However I'm getting only `owner.entity`  field and `owner.entityId` is missing.

The service account I'm using has assigned a role with the following permissions:

```
storage.buckets.list
storage.objects.get
storage.objects.getIamPolicy
storage.objects.list
```

I checked also granting to service account an Owner role at the project level but it did not help.

The scope I use in the JWT is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control`

Comment: What command do you use? Are you using Try this API?

Comment: @JavierA I'm calling API object list endpoint https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list

Comment: Hello, there is an [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/203625328) about this. I suggest indicating you are affected by it or sharing any meaningful information in order to give it more visibility.

Comment: @JavierA Thanks for the link. I will monitor it.